# Finding the max per grouped variable and convert in new variables

Tags: r

I have the following data set and I would like to identify the product with the highest amount per customer_ID and convert it into a new column.  I also want to keep only one record per ID.

Data to generate the data set:

`x <- data.frame(customer_id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2), 
      product=c("a","b","c","a","b","c"), 
      amount=c(50,125,100,75,110,150))`

Actual data set looks like this:

`customer_id product amount
1            a       50
1            b       125
1            c       100
2            a       75
2            b       110
2            c       150`

Desired output wanted should look like this:

`customer_ID  product_b product_c
1            125       0
2            0         150`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this with `tidyverse`.  After grouping by 'customer_id', `slice` the row that has the maximum 'amount', `paste` with prefix ('product_') to 'product' column (if needed) and `spread` to wide format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
x %>%
   group_by(customer_id) %>% 
   slice(which.max(amount)) %>% 
   mutate(product = paste0("product_", product)) %>%
   spread(product, amount, fill = 0)
#  customer_id product_b product_c
#*       <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#1           1       125         0
#2           2         0       150
```

---

Another option is to `arrange` the dataset by 'customer_id' and 'amount' in descending order, get the `distinct` rows based on 'customer_id' and `spread to 'wide'

```
arrange(x, customer_id, desc(amount)) %>%
        distinct(customer_id, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
        spread(customer_id, amount, fill = 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `reshape2` package,

```
library(reshape2)

x1 <- x[!!with(x, ave(amount, customer_id, FUN = function(i) i == max(i))),]

dcast(x1, customer_id ~ product, value.var = 'amount', fill = 0)
#  customer_id   b   c
#1           1 125   0
#2           2   0 150
```